# TypeScript: Insert a 'type' field in an object from an associated type

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have several associated types, something like this:

```js
interface MyObject {
    type: string,
}

interface MyObjectHandle {
    type: string,
    id: number,
}

type Foo = {
    type: 'foo',
    foo: string,
}
type FooHandle = {
    id: number,
    type: 'foo',
}

type Bar = {
    type: 'bar',
    bar: string,
    baz: number,
}
type BarHandle = {
    id: string,
    type: 'bar',
}

type FooBar = Foo | Bar;
type FooBarHandle = FooHandle | BarHandle;
```

Now, given a `Foo` or a `Bar`, I'd like to do some stuff, assign an id, and then return the associated `FooHandle` or `BarHandle`.

But something like this won't work:

```js
insertMyObject<T extends MyObject>(context: Context, object: T): {
    const id = uniqid.time();
    context.addToTheMap(id, object);
    context.insertHandleIntoAThing({
        type: object.type,
        id: id
    });
}
```

Why? Because `insertHandleIntoAThing` expects a type of `FooBar`. Now, its obvious that given the associated types, only `foo` or `bar` are valid and therefore this should compile. But typescript can't prove that.

I *could*, rather than having `FooHandle` and `BarHandle`, just have one single `MyObjectHandle` type. But I'd like to see if there's a solution without that. Perhaps my defining some associated type, and telling typescript that these handles are somehow associated with the original objects?

Thanks,

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/Nd37Yw), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this perhaps?

```
type FooBarHandle<T> = T extends FooHandle
    ? FooHandle
    : BarHandle;
function insertMyObject<
    T extends FooBarHandle<FooHandle | BarHandle>
>(context: Record<any, any>, object: T) {
    const id = 'uniqueID';
    context.addToTheMap(id, object);
    context.insertHandleIntoAThing({
        type: object.type === 'foo' ? 'foo' : 'bar',
        id: id
    });
}
```

Comment: If you could provide a more explicit context it'd help me conceptualize the use-case and how to better approach this perhaps.